# OnOpen/OnEdit Pop-Up Based on Cell Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google Scripts and what I'm basically trying to do is: if the word "LATE" appears anywhere in the spreadsheet, I want a pop-up to appear with the phrase "Please check the master tracker" and I want to send an email to a list of specified people.

I've experimented with the onOpen function, but as that runs the script literally every time someone opens the spreadsheet that's not what I'm looking for.

```
    function onOpen() {
       var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
       ui.alert('Please check the master tracker');
       }""
```

I've also played around with the onEdit function because the word "LATE" is set in the Google Sheets function bar to appear based on a specified number of days per task. For example, an item request has a 5 day lag time:

```
      =IF(TODAY()>=C21+5, "LATE","")
```

A review request has a 2 day lag time:

```
      =IF(TODAY()>=C21+2, "LATE","")
```

And an executive review request has a 14 day lag time:

```
      =IF(TODAY()>=C21+14, "LATE","")
```

However, the onEdit function only runs when a **user** makes changes, not when a function makes changes.

**So how can I get a popup to run whenever the word "LATE" appears in any of the sheets, when the word "LATE" is part of an automatic function?** Any help or guidance would be tremendously appreciated, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: All you can do is poll for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling once a minute

```
function myfunk {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(ss.createTextFinder("LATE").findAll().length > 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please check the master tracker");
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let recipients = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().join(",");
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients,"Subject","Message");
  }
}
```

Polling trigger:

```
function createMyTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "myfunk").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("myfunk").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
  }
}
```

- [ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app)

Comment: Cooper, thank you so much for your help—that code works perfectly! As a follow-up, do you know how I might go about embedding a link in the pop-up alert (and email) that takes a user directly to or highlights all instances of the word "LATE"?